# How can I expire a user session after a certain period of inactivity?

Tags: reactjs, session, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm working on a serverless Reactjs project, and I'm using AWS amplify to manage my users. I've noticed in testing, that if I log in as a user, I'm still logged in the next day when I go to the site. I read Amplify's documentation that the library automatically refreshes the tokens, and was wondering if it is possible to disable this feature, so that the user will have to re-sign in to the site, after a few hours of inactivity.

Thank you.

Comment: Now it seems to be possible but I failed to find the exact way to do this.
https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-cognito-user-pools-supports-customization-of-token-expiration/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no way to set an expiry timeout for token in Amplify or force the token to expire. The work around is to set a time in your React app and do [Global SignOut](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#re-send-confirmation-code) after your desired timeout value to revoke all the token including id, access and refresh tokens.

This is an open issue and you can find more details about it on the links below.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1972

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2714

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can set access, refresh and ID token expiration time through the Amazon Cognito Console.
It was added in [August 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-cognito-user-pools-supports-customization-of-token-expiration/).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html