# How to revoke tokens in Amplify JS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I would like to know How to revoke tokens specially Revoke Token Refresh of my Session in Amplify JS with AWS Cognito. Thanks

Comment: Does this help?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62557774/aws-amplify-how-to-expire-user-session-after-certain-time-of-inactivity/62562394#62562394

Answer (score 0):

To revoke your refresh token from client-side you will need to use the global signout parameter in your `Auth.signout({ global: true })` function

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
async function signOut() {
    try {
        await Auth.signOut({ global: true });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing out: ', error);
    }
}
```